# Why can't is my activation hook function not found in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

In my main WordPress plugin file, I have the below code. WordPress keeps throwing the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "WCSEA_activate" not found or invalid function name`

I am not sure why it doesn't find the functions when the names match with the names in the hook.

```
<?php

//Plugin header comment

namespace WCSEA;

// More code

/**
 * Include class autoloader.
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
require_once WCSEA_PATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin activation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-wcsea-activator.php
 */
function WCSEA_activate() {
    Activator::activate();
}

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin deactivation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-wcsea-deactivator.php
 */
function WCSEA_deactivate() {
    Deactivator::deactivate();
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'WCSEA_activate');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'WCSEA_deactivate');


// rest of the code
```